# Aria2c URI parameter issue

Tags: bsc

```
aria2c –o get.tar.lz4 –x 4 –s 12 "https://tf-dex-prod-public-snapshot.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/geth-20220603.tar.lz4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAYINE6SBQPUZDDRRO&Signature=vfHuvLkeO0iTBmPz10HTANzSOX4%3D&Expires=1656939101"
```

This produces this error.

```
Exception caught
Exception: [download_helper.cc:451] errorCode=1 Unrecognized URI or unsupported protocol: –o
```

I replaced -o by -O but I think it has to do with the URLs? anyone same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You use "–" and in not right. instead "-"

```
 aria2c -o get.tar.lz4 -x 4 -s 12 "https://tf-dex-prod-public-snapshot.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/geth-20220603.tar.lz4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAYINE6SBQPUZDDRRO&Signature=vfHuvLkeO0iTBmPz10HTANzSOX4%3D&Expires=1656939101"
```